# Jetpack compose: Scaffold navigationBarsPadding not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, scaffold

I'm using Jetpack compose with Scaffold. As you can see it doesn't work properly.

```
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .navigationBarsPadding(),
) {
    ...
}
```

[image]

Note that I have called `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` on host activity.

Also this result is happing on **Lg G4 - Api 26**

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this code, set in your root

```
ProvideWindowInsets {}
```

Comment: It's deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` ：Indicates that the content can extend to the system bar

In your case, you can use：`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)`

**Example**:

```
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: But what if `decorFitsSystemWindows = true` is required for animating layout size based in IME insets? This is exactly my case.